# ByteArry to file not working in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to convert ByteArry to file in Angularjs.

Json :

```
[{"byFileName":"[B@7619acc3","strMimeType":"image\/gif"}]
```

Angularjs :

```
  $scope.docDownload = function(docName){
    alert("docDownload");
     $http.get("processRequest.jsp?requestType=docDownload&strDocname="+docName).then(function(response) {

           var byteArray = response.data[0].byFileName;
           var blob = new Blob([byteArray], { type: response.data[0].strMimeType});
            if (window.navigator && window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
                window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(blob);
            }
            else {
                var objectUrl = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
                window.open(objectUrl);
            }
  });
}
```

Please suggest to me, Where is my mistake?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Convert your **`byFileName`** `bytearray` into real type(using `Uint8Array`) and then create `Blob`.

`var byteArray = new Uint8Array(response.data[0].byFileName);`

Also, you need to mention `{responseType:'arraybuffer'}`, for your `$http.get()`. 
See this working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sL73p5o4/)

Comment: Thanks :) not working I am getting in browser blob:http://localhost:9004/5ecdd28c-698b-406e-866d-b166cf438149

Comment: @j.Doe: Is your source array correct,? See this working [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sL73p5o4/),

Comment: No problem in bytearray. I was tried byteArray to file in java it working fine

Comment: In your question the bytearray you try to convert into Blob is :`[B@7619acc3`, which seems to be wrong., could you please provide response of `  $http.get(url..)` ?